# Evince opening pdf via terminal but not via file manager

Tags: 12.10, pdf, evince

Fresh install of lubuntu 12.10. Tried opening PDF files with Document Viewer (evince) by double clicking but once the application opens I am presented with a red bar saying "No such file or directory".

So I thought I would run `evince file.pdf`
to see if any errors are displayed. But none... The document opens as expected.

Why the discrepancy? I really don't want to use terminal every time I want to open a PDF.

*---More info---*
Filenames like:

- 2012_expense_report_week#32.pdf
- $100-$200_Donators.pdf
- 2013_budget~draft3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with file naming conventions it turns out that the # character was the culprit. I used a bulk renaming script to remove them as well as all other non-alphanumeric characters and now everything is peachy.

I am not sure if this is the general rule because the files opened normally on Ubuntu Gnome Remix (nautilus file manager).

Maybe this is only an issue when using Lubuntu (pcfileman file manager).

Comment: That sounds like a good candidate to a bug report.

Comment: Can you please **edit your question** to provide exact examples of filenames that work and don't work in Lubuntu (by double-clicking and via the terminal).

Comment: @Fitoschido I will look into posting a bug report, If I can somehow confirm it is a bug.

Comment: @vasa1 I will update the question as requested.

Comment: Of the three files you have included in the question, only one has the **#** which was implicated in the answer as being responsible for the problem. Additionally, I would avoid things like **$**, **~** and **#** in filenames.

Comment: I assumed so. Even though they weren't causing any problems, I made a point of removing all non-alphanumeric characters. except for underscores and hyphens.